# Django Celery crontab every certain day of the week

Tags: django, cron, django-celery

Im a bit confused. I want to send a taks every Wednesday and this is how I have set it.

```
0 12 3 * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)
```

Would that not send it every day? Or would the day of week override day of month? Or how should it be set to send only on specified day of week?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cron tasks only execute when every condition is met.

```
0 12 3 * * command
```

checks every minute whether:

- Minute is 0 **AND**
- Hour is 12 **AND**
- Weekday is Wednesday **AND**
- Day of month is whatever **AND**
- Month of year is whatever

and if all these apply executes `command`.

Here weekday is the crucial argument of course, because only on wednesday its … wednesday!
If you would omit the weekday argument then on 12:00 the condition set up in your cron task would be true, thus the task would be executed every day.

You may also want to have a look at http://cronwtf.github.io/ for experimenting around a bit.

Comment: Oh, the link is broken. I use https://crontab.guru for experimenting